# Why is there a syntax error on pyspark broadcast call

Tags: pyspark

I'm following a textbook example about creating a music recommender and when trying to set up the alias connection to link incorrect names to the correct names in the artist name column, I'm getting a syntax error.

The error is on line 3 and its on the broadcast call.  It has an issue with the how='left'

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast, when

train_data = user_artist_df.join(broadcast(artist_alias),'artist', how='left').\ //here is the error

train_data = train_data.withColumn('artist',
                                        when(col('alias').isNull(), col('artist')).\
                                        otherwise(col('alias')))

train_data = train_data.withColumn('artist', col('artist').\
                                                cast(IntegerType())).\
                                                drop('alias')

train_data.cache()

train_data.count()
```

Comment: what does the error say? why do you have the .\ at the end of the join?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4
    train_data = user_artist_df.join(broadcast(artist_alias), 'artist', how="left").\

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oh I got it.  It was the enter that was throwing issues.  Thank you so much! I'll make a note on errata to let the publisher know.

Comment: please post yourself as an answer or @samkart and mark that as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `./` at the end of line 3 that is causing the error. This should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast, when

train_data = user_artist_df.join(broadcast(artist_alias),'artist', how='left')

train_data = train_data.withColumn('artist',
                                        when(col('alias').isNull(), col('artist')).\
                                        otherwise(col('alias')))

train_data = train_data.withColumn('artist', col('artist').\
                                                cast(IntegerType())).\
                                                drop('alias')

train_data.cache()

train_data.count()
```